# DefaultItemAnimator NullPointerException - stack trace not pointing at app's code

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have no idea how to fix this and what causes it. So far it happened only on one device from one user (seems very rare) and this stack trace and some device details is all I have to fix this issue (reported by crash reporting).

Android version: 24 (7.0)

Does anyone know what could cause this exception?

```
Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$w.a' on a null object reference
android.support.v7.widget.ak.a (DefaultItemAnimator.java:153)
android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$2.run (RecyclerView.java:433)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:871)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:683)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:616)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:857)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6247)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:872)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:762)
```